# xpath - pick based on another child of parent node

Tags: xpath

I have page that looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="span class one">
                some text
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="span class two">
                span i want to pick
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pick `<span class="span class two">` by text thats in `<span class="span class one">`. I am not sure if it is even possible. Number of elements is not same in each tree part.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a much more representative example? Currently, your example does not represent your last statement which is "Number of elements is not same in each tree part."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following could be the alternative answer -

```
//span[normalize-space(text())='some text']/../../following-sibling::div//span
```

Explanation :-

`//span[normalize-space(text())='some text']` is used to find the span tag with required details

`/../..` will move to parent element of context node

`/following-sibling::div//span` will locate the `span` tag which in sibling element of parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element by the value of the class attribute with:

```
//span[@class='span class two']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//span[contains(., "some text")]/following::span
```

out:

```
Element='<span class="span class two">
                span i want to pick
            </span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, as you were mentioned that you want to create `xpath` along with `span class one`

```
//span[text()= 'some text']/following::span[@class='span class two']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag using `following keyword`.

Comment: Does my explanation of code `helped` you? if it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted`

Answer (score 0):

I might've understood it differently but I'll try to give out a different answer:
`//span[contains(text(),(//span[@class='span class one']/text())) and not(@class='span class one')]`

which means:

`//span[contains(text(),` - you're looking for a span element that contains a certain text

`(//span[@class='span class one']/text()))`- that text is whatever is the text in span class one

`and not(@class='span class one')]` - but the span element should not be span class one

of course you can replace `text()` with a different property such as class or name or whatever... e.g. `//span[contains(@class,(//span[@class='span class one']/text()))]`

Comment: This is also good solution. I didnt test it, but it looks pretty smart.